Issue with connecting Arduino to my Flask API
When I try to start my Flask API this error appears:

could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Odmowa dostępu.', None, 5)

How can I fix it?
I checked device manager and in displayed in port section are

Arduino Uno (COM3)
Communications Port(COM1)

I have closed Arduino IDE.
Python code
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import serial
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)


motion_status = "Brak ruchu"

def read_from_arduino():
    global motion_status
    while True:
        data = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8').strip() 
        if data:
            motion_status = data
            time.sleep(0.1)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/status')
def status():
    return jsonify(status=motion_status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_arduino)
    thread.daemon= True
    thread.start()

    app.run(debug=True)


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain clearly how your flask project works.  It isn't clear why it's trying to access COM3.  What does your flask project look like?  Don't you need to be root to access com3?  (unless of course, you change the permissions...   been sometime since I've used a comport.)

The answers here may be helpful.

I for now I want to create some basic I want to send signal to my flask API do display that movement was found my code looks like this - I added my code to the post
